# Problema con la tabla Pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent

He modificado esta pregunta. Ahora he organizado un poco mas el problema creando una tabla pivot. Por que veo que mi relacion lo amerita.

Estoy relacionando la una tabla Users con las tablas Cliente, Operador y supervisor de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero lograr con esto es que cada cliente, supervisor y operador tenga un usuario asociado para tener el acceso al sistema. Y que a su vez un operador tenga muchos clientes asociados y que los supervisores tengan muchos operadores asociados.

He creado las migraciones así como muestro en la imagen.

Este es mi modelo user:

```
public function supervisores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supervisor::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function operadores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Operador::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function clientes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}
```

Este es mi modelo Supervisor:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function operadores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Operador::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function clientes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}
```

Este es mi modelo Operador:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function supervisores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supervisor::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function clientes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Cliente::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}
```

Este es mi modelo Cliente:

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function operadores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Operador::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}

public function supervisores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Supervisor::class, 'cliente_operador_supervisor_user');
}
```

Estoy intentando crear un supervisor asociandole un usuario y me sale este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trantando de guardar los datos a traves de esta consulta:

```
public function store(SaveSupervisorRequest $request)
{   
    $data = $request->except(['user_id']);
    $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
    Supervisor::create($data);
    $user->supervisores()->attach(1);

    return redirect()->route('supervisores.index')->with('success', 'El supervisor fue creado con éxito!');
}
```

Comment: @BetaM ya lo hice.

Comment: @BetaM entiendo lo que dices. Acabo de cambiar a belongsToMany, pero me sigue dando el inconveniente. Realmente estoy un poco confundido con el asunto de las relaciones. Voy a seguir tu consejo y leere de nuevo toda la doc

Comment: @BetaM he modificado la pregunta, espero me puedas ayudar.

Comment: @BetaM Listo. Disculpa soy principiante.

Comment: Estoy probando, porque no se como pasarle directamente el Id del supervisor creado recientemente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con estas 2 líneas ya estás *creando al supervisor*

```
$data = $request->except(['user_id']);
Supervisor::create($data);
```

Aunque desconozco por que razón quitas el atributo `user_id`

Lo que puedes hacer es asignar a una variable dicha creación y posterior por medio de esa recuperar el id del objeto recién almacenado.

```
$supervisorCreado = Supervisor::create($data);
$idSupervisorCreado = $supervisorCreado->id;
```

Ahora puedes en otra variable obtener el id del usuario que le quieres asociar

```
$usuarioAsociado = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);
```

Finalmente construyes la query que haga el registro de estos 2 valores asociados:

```
$nuevoSupervisorConUsuario = $idSupervisorCreado->users()->attach($usuarioAsociado);
```

**Referencias**

- [attaching y detaching en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Estaba excluyendo el user_id porque en el formulario para crear el supervisor tengo de select donde muestro a que usuario asociar.

Comment: Si ya funciono. Corregi dos lineas de lo que pusiste porque me daba un error, pero ya esta todo muy bien. Gracias mil!

Comment: @BPolanco si ya noté el por que, estaba invocando a la relación `supervisores` pero esa en supervisores no existe, la relación correcta para esta respuesta que estoy dando es `users`